# Convert Subdivision Curve to Bezier Curve

Tags: graphics, digital-curve

Wondering if there is a way technically to convert a [Subdivision Curve](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g-fall2010/lectures/lecture17-Subdivision_curves.pdf) into a [Bezier Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves).

Comment: That's a little broad and depends highly on the specific subdivision scheme as well as the order of the Bezier curve (and if with curve you actually mean "spline"). As you'll notice from your linked presentation, some subdivision schemes actually converge to B-splines already, which can in turn be reformulated as Bezier splines.